# Unable to imperatively route to portal after form submit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

Once I have the user login to my app, I want to imperatively redirect to the portal page. However, 3 things happen when I call router.navigate()... 1) The app redirects to /portal. 2) The app then immediately redirects to /portal again with Email Address and Password as query strings. 3) The app then seems to "reset" somehow, losing appState.User (completely "forgetting" the user has already logged in), so the app redirects me back to the original login page. What's the problem here?

This is all happening inside of a form onSubmit which gets triggered by this button:

```
<button type="submit" (click)="onSubmit(Form)">Sign in</button>
```

Here's the onSubmit code:

```
public onSubmit(form: EmailForm): void {
    this.apiLogin.LoginUser(form.EmailAddress, form.Password).subscribe(
        (user: LoginUser) => {
            if(user.UserToken == null) {
                this.addValidationError("Invalid username and/or password.");
            }
            else {
                this.appState.setUser(user);
            }
        },
        (err) => {},
        () => {
            this.router.navigate(['/portal']);
        }
    );
}
```

Here's my route setup as well...

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: '', component: HomeComponent, pathMatch: 'full' },
    { path: 'portal', component: PortalComponent, canActivate: [AuthGuard] },
    { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];
```

You may not need it, but here's the AuthGuard service I'm using on the portal route. Thanks @Sasxa for [helping me setup this AuthGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853352/cant-get-app-to-navigate-to-portal).

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private appState: ApplicationState, private router: Router) {}

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
        let url: string = state.url;
        return this.checkLogin(url);
    }

    checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
        if (this.appState.User.UserToken) return true;

        this.navToLogin(url);
        return false;
    }

    private navToLogin(redirUrl: string) {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
    }
}   // end class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had made a small mistake of using (click) instead of (ngSubmit). Fixed this way:

```
(ngSubmit)="onSubmit(Form)"
```